# SWT (mouse)ScrollBar not working while scrolling through the results set

Tags: java, database, operating-system, scrollbar, swt

I am using SWT ScrollBar/Slider to scroll through my resultset.
When I use the vertical scroll bar(see pic), it allows me to scroll through the results without any problem. But when I use mouse scroll, it gets stuck after fetching a certain no. of rows, and now if I go back to using the vertical scroll, it allows me to scroll through the remaining results.

```
ScrollBar sbar = this.getVerticalBar();
    if (sbar != null)
    {
        sbar.setEnabled(true);
        sbar.setVisible(false);
        sbar.setValues(4, 0, 10, 1, 1, 3);
        sbar.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener()
        {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e)
            {
                // Cancels editing
                cancelEdit(true);
          
                final int selection = ((ScrollBar)e.widget).getSelection();
                m_vertBar.setSelection(selection);
                GridSWT.this.vScrollTo(selection);
            }

            public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e)
            {
            }
        });
    }
```

Can anyone pls help me fix it?
Would be really helpful.

Thanks,
Ashish[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgQEm.png)

Comment: Can you not use the JFace TableViewer? It handles all scrolling and editing support. You would need to show us a proper [mre] to understand what this code is trying to do.

Comment: No, I actually can't use the JFace. Sure, let me try and provide you with an example, so that you paint a better picture out of it.